# Twisted: Slowing down dataReceived

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

Let's say I receive data over a TCP connection at a fast rate. I have to do some kind of processing on it. Since I don't want to block the reactor thread, I offload the processing to a background thread.

The data arrives faster than I can process it. If I put the data in a queue, the queue grows infinitely.

**Is there a way to tell twisted to pause receiving data?**

The TCP protocol can force the sender to slow down. This is what would happen if I'd do the processing the reactor thread (which isn't an option as there are other, better behaved, TCP connections around).

Comment: @barny That's what I was trying to say in the last paragraph. Data wouldn't get lost. The TCP protocol takes are of that. The operating system on the sender side will slow sending down.

Comment: Deleted my dumb comment. Is this any use http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2015-January/029068.html  However I think you might have to figure out how to actually slow the producer down, so it limits the data rate.

Comment: How about: run the data processing script in one process (not thread) - it blocks so data gets throttled - and run the rest in another process and on different ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are implementing a subclass of `Protocol`, your `transport` attribute is probably an [`IPushProducer`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.3.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IPushProducer.html), which means you just need to call `self.transport.pauseProducing()` and then `self.transport.resumeProducing()` whenever you'd like it to start giving you data again.  If you just want to rate-limit, you can call `resumeProducing()` after a brief delay, using `reactor.callLater()`.